# Лагает пользовательский интерфейс

Tags: android, вёрстка, оптимизация

Никак не могу найти нужной мне информации:

есть приложение на android, - на activity размещено много элементов ImageView. Как можно добиться использования меньшей памяти приложением, при большом количестве картинок (формат png)?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте их отображать через библиотеку `Glide`. Так же может помочь уменьшение размеров картинок + разбиаение их на размеры под разные плотности экранов. Так на мальних плотностях будут использоваться маленькие картинки и памяти они будут меньше отъедать

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Comment: Хм, посмотрел библиотеку , не подгружаю изобрадения из инета они внутри приложения, вес постараюсь езе максимальнее ужать , лучше всего ведь подходит png формат? Возможно я делаб разметку активи не удачноц в работоспосоюности у меня Constain внутри которого два Table и один Relative

Comment: @Александр, вроде Glide умеет и не из сети картинки отображать. И да, кажется у вас не оптимальная разметка. Попробуйте её упростить

Comment: была похожая проблема из-за перегруженности интерфейса. Посмотрите, как я ее решал - https://habrahabr.ru/post/279979/